# Mac suddenly stopped connecting to websites

Tags: domain-name-system, mac

I had a mac that was connecting to the network just fine, and then today it still connected to the network, but when I tried to go to different sites, it just hung there saying "waiting for website..."

Would anyone know why that might have happened? I read somewhere it might be a DNS issue. But how do I debug this? I already rebooted everything and the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be various reasons for that. First of all try to find out if the network/internet connection on the computer really works.

First try to ping an local IP or your gateway. If that works it means that your LAN works. Then try to ping let's say google DNS server (`ping 8.8.8`). If that works it means also the internet works for you.

One chance is that it's a DNS related problem. Try to use 8.8.8.8 as an DNS and reopen a web page. If it still doesn't work check if you have enabled/disabled any kind of web proxy.

Hope that helps.